# include_directories and CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building two C++ libraries(2 CMake projects). `library2` depends on `library1`. I am installing my first library header files at `${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylibraries`. Now to include `library1` header files in my `library2`, I am doing `include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylibraries)` in the `library2`'s `CMakeLists.txt`.

But the make is failing with `no such file or directory` error.

`library1.h` no such file or directory from `library2.cpp`

**library1's CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
project (logger)
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)
set (Umbrella "ferryfair")
# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file (
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
    )
configure_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/pkgconfig.pc.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig.pc"
    )

set (GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++14")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")
file(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR}/${Umbrella})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}Static STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}Static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}
    )
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}Static
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}
    )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}Static ferrybase)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ferrybase)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}Static DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${Umbrella})
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${Umbrella}
    RENAME ${PROJECT_NAME}Config.h)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig.pc"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig
    RENAME "${PROJECT_NAME}.pc")
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig.pc"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig
    RENAME "${PROJECT_NAME}.pc")
```

**library2's CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
project (FFJSON)
IF (DEFINED _DEBUG)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_DEBUG=${_DEBUG})
ENDIF()
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)
set (Umbrella "ferryfair")
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
# Mac OS X specific code
SET(macOS ON)
ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file (
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
    )
configure_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/pkgconfig.pc.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/pkgconfig.pc"
    )

set (GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++14")
set (GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs")
IF (DEFINED _DEBUG)
set (GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -g -O0")
set (GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS} -g -O0")
ENDIF()
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")
file(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR}/${Umbrella})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}Static STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}Static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}
    )
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}Static
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}
    )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}Static logger ferrybase)
target_include_directories(TestFFJSON PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${Umbrella}>
    )

add_executable(IteratorIncrement tests/iteratorincrement.cpp)
target_link_libraries(IteratorIncrement FFJSON logger ferrybase)
target_include_directories(IteratorIncrement PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${Umbrella}>
    )

add_test(test1 TestFFJSON)
add_test(test2 IteratorIncrement)
ENDIF()
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we are able to see exactly what your code is doing. You haven't given enough information for us to determine the issue.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits please let me know if actual `CMakeLists.txt` files will be actually helpful

Comment: Yes, it would be.

Comment: @CinderBicuits updated with `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Its weird! ridiculous! pathetic!

executing `cmake` twice fixed the issue. Its an another entry into accidental discoveries.

Comment: I build in a clean folder